# Weird artifacts when importing texture to Unity

Tags: texture-baking, uv-image-editor, unity

I have this tree texture that I UV Mapped and the bark should be a single color as it is in Blender. But when I import the texture and apply it to the model in Unity I get these dark stripes. I have tried changing the compression values of the UV Map image but it doesn't really do anything.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Edit: Turns out it was the emission value of the material in blender. I had put the same color as the base color but way darker as suggested in a YouTube tutorial but when I put the same value as the base color the lines disappeared.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unity is less precise when it comes to texture sampling. This means, it can accidentally pick a pixel outside the UV island. Can you show the texture, preferably with the UV Layout?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz Yeah I've realized that after reading a few other posts. I uploaded the UV Map, hopefully that's what you meant.